# Shortest code to read TChecklistBox checked Items

Tags: delphi

what is the shortest code to copy all checked items from a TChecklistBox into a TStringlist ?

( for a TListbox I can you the assign function to add and extract a TStringlist with data)

Comment: why do you need shortest code ? Actually i know International Obfuscated Code context, i also remember there was FastCode contest for Delphi, but i do not remember seeing shortest code contest anywhere. VCL is just not intended to create smallest possible EXE, though i remember i managed to make 2KB DLL in Delphi 5 :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The I think Franz means the shortest source code rather than the smallest object code

Comment: @Arioch, see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. There's a lot of them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan big difference... usually that corresponds in average unless some synthetic cases.

Comment: @Tlama, thanks, i knew i missed something. Guess we need mods to move this question where it belongs to.

Answer (score 5):

Using plain vanilla Delphi (i.e. without any third party libraries) you just write a `for` loop:

```
StringList.Clear;
for i := 0 to CheckListBox.Items.Count-1 do
  if CheckListBox.Checked[i] then
    StringList.Add(CheckListBox.Items[i]);
```

Comment: OK,  no chance to avoid that loop at read out ?

Comment: I believe not. It's easy to put the code in a class helper.

Comment: I can't think of how to make this any simpler. Why don't you want to use a loop? That's clearly the solution to make this the "shortest code".